# My python multiprocesing code is slower than serial one

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am trying to implement a image processing technique "Local thickness" in python and opencv. It has been implemented in image analysis software called ImageJ. Basically for a binary image, the algorithm will

1. skeletonize any white objects (to create skeleton or ridge)
2. for each skeleton/ridge point, find the distance to closest edge
3. for any point within this distance, assign the thickness value to be the distance, or update the thickness if the distance is larger than existing thickness value

The part I want to implement using multiprocessing is 3. The original code is [here](https://github.com/fiji/LocalThickness/blob/LocalThickness_-4.0.2/src/main/java/sc/fiji/localThickness/Local_Thickness_Parallel.java). In python, I divided all the skeleton/ridge points into chunks and pass each chuck to a process. All processes communicate through one share array which stores the thickness value. However, my multiprocessing code is slower than serial, even for any one process which only will process portion of the data.

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from skimage.morphology import medial_axis
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def worker(sRidge_shared,iRidge,jRidge,rRidge,w,h,iR_worker,worker):
    print('Job starting for worker',worker)
    start=time.time()
    for iR in iR_worker:
        i = iRidge[iR];
        j = jRidge[iR];
        r = rRidge[iR];
        rSquared = int(r * r + 0.5)
        rInt = int(r)
        if (rInt < r): rInt+=1
        iStart = i - rInt
        if (iStart < 0): iStart = 0
        iStop = i + rInt
        if (iStop >= w): iStop = w - 1
        jStart = j - rInt
        if (jStart < 0): jStart = 0
        jStop = j + rInt
        if (jStop >= h): jStop = h - 1
        for j1 in range(jStart,jStop):
            r1SquaredJ =  (j1 - j) * (j1 - j)
            if (r1SquaredJ <= rSquared):
                for i1 in range(iStart,iStop):
                    r1Squared = r1SquaredJ + (i1 - i) * (i1 - i)
                    if (r1Squared <= rSquared):
                        if (rSquared > sRidge_shared[i1+j1*w]):
                            sRidge_shared[i1+j1*w] = rSquared
    print('Worker',worker,' finished job in ',time.time()-start, 's')



def Ridge_to_localthickness_parallel(ridgeimg):
    w, h = ridgeimg.shape
    M = coo_matrix(ridgeimg)
    nR = M.count_nonzero()
    iRidge = M.row
    jRidge = M.col
    rRidge = M.data
    sRidge = np.zeros((w*h,))
    sRidge_shared = mp.Array('d', sRidge)

    nproc = 10

    p = [mp.Process(target=worker,
                    args=(sRidge_shared,iRidge,jRidge,rRidge,w,h,range(i*nR//nproc,min((i+1)*nR//nproc,nR)),i))
                    for i in range(nproc)]
    for pc in p:
        pc.start()
    for pc in p:
        pc.join()

    a = np.frombuffer(sRidge_shared.get_obj())
    b = a.reshape((h,w))

    return 2*np.sqrt(b)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mp.freeze_support()
    size = 1024

    img = np.zeros((size,size), np.uint8)
    cv.ellipse(img,(size//2,size//2),(size//3,size//5),0,0,360,255,-1)

    skel, distance = medial_axis(img, return_distance=True)
    dist_on_skel = distance * skel

    start = time.time()
    LT1 = Ridge_to_localthickness_parallel(dist_on_skel)
    print('Multiprocessing elapsed time: ', time.time() - start, 's')
```

Here is the result:

```
Serial elapsed time:  71.07010626792908 s
Job starting for worker 0
Job starting for worker 1
Job starting for worker 2
Job starting for worker 3
Job starting for worker 4
Job starting for worker 5
Job starting for worker 7
Job starting for worker 6
Job starting for worker 8
Job starting for worker 9
Worker 0  finished job in  167.6777663230896 s
Worker 9  finished job in  181.82518076896667 s
Worker 1  finished job in  211.21311926841736 s
Worker 8  finished job in  211.43014097213745 s
Worker 7  finished job in  235.29852747917175 s
Worker 2  finished job in  241.1481122970581 s
Worker 6  finished job in  242.3452320098877 s
Worker 3  finished job in  247.0727047920227 s
Worker 5  finished job in  245.52154970169067 s
Worker 4  finished job in  246.9776954650879 s
Multiprocessing elapsed time:  256.9716944694519 s
>>>
```

I am running this on a windows machine. I have not try multithreading since I don't know how to access a shared array for multithreading.

Edit:

I have used sharedmem and Thread/ThreadPoolExecutor. The result got better than multiprocessing but not serial one.

```
Serial elapsed time:  67.51724791526794 s
Job starting for worker 0
Job starting for worker 1
Job starting for worker 2
Job starting for worker 3
Job starting for worker 4
Job starting for worker 6
Job starting for worker 5
Job starting for worker 7
Job starting for worker 8
Job starting for worker 9
Job starting for worker 10
Job starting for worker 11
Job starting for worker 12
Job starting for worker 13
Job starting for worker 14
Job starting for worker 15
Job starting for worker 16
Job starting for worker 17
Job starting for worker 18
Job starting for worker 19
Worker 2  finished job in  60.84959959983826 s
Worker 3  finished job in  63.856611013412476 s
Worker 4  finished job in  67.02961277961731 s
Worker 16  finished job in  68.00975942611694 s
Worker 15  finished job in  70.39874267578125 s
Worker 1  finished job in  75.65659618377686 s
Worker 14  finished job in  76.97173047065735 s
Worker 9  finished job in  78.4876492023468 s
Worker 0  finished job in  87.56459546089172 s
Worker 7  finished job in  89.86062669754028 s
Worker 17  finished job in  91.72178316116333 s
Worker 8  finished job in  94.22166323661804 s
Worker 19  finished job in  93.27084946632385 s
Worker 13  finished job in  95.02370047569275 s
Worker 5  finished job in  98.98063397407532 s
Worker 18  finished job in  97.57283663749695 s
Worker 10  finished job in  103.78466653823853 s
Worker 11  finished job in  105.19767212867737 s
Worker 6  finished job in  105.96561932563782 s
Worker 12  finished job in  105.5306978225708 s
Threading elapsed time:  106.97455644607544 s
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing an array over several processes has a huge cost.

Basically this is how to "estimate" the time for a multi processing :

- Time to share all the data
- Time to compute (which should be slower than your serial compute, as it is supposed to compute less)
- Aggregate the results.

Here I highly suspect the first step to come with a huge cost (big arrays)

Usually you can multiprocess / multithreading easily part of code which can be easily separable (which do not need the full array)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. The second step you mentioned, should be faster than serial code, right? I guess I will have to look up OpenCV code for dilation since the code I implement is essentially a dilation with customized shape and size for each point.

Comment: if I ran this in Linux, does the first step you mentioned still a issue? I have briefly read that for Windows, multiprocessing will create separate processes and gather all data.

Comment: You are right, I meant faster * I will edit my answer. On linux that Can run a bit faster, but not sure at all

Comment: No. But I did modify the code so all processes won't share the large matrix as input. However I have to have them return the same matrix. It doesn't help. I'll try to let it return a sparse form matrix. It might speed things up.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, I will delete my answer soon !